# Consuming SAML XML Response in ColdFusion

Tags: soap, coldfusion, saml

We are currently developing a SOAP API request that requires a SAML Authentication:

Here is the response we got from the Security Token Service of our provider:

```xml
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
    <s:Header>
        <a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1">http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-trust/200512/RSTRC/IssueFinal</a:Action>
        <o:Security s:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:o="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
            <u:Timestamp u:Id="_0">
                <u:Created>2019-05-28T03:58:09.114Z</u:Created>
                <u:Expires>2019-05-28T04:03:09.114Z</u:Expires>
            </u:Timestamp>
        </o:Security>
    </s:Header>
    <s:Body>
        <trust:RequestSecurityTokenResponseCollection xmlns:trust="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-trust/200512">
            <trust:RequestSecurityTokenResponse>
                <trust:KeySize>256</trust:KeySize>
                <trust:Lifetime>
                    <wsu:Created xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">2019-05-28T03:58:09.114Z</wsu:Created>
                    <wsu:Expires xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">2019-05-28T04:58:09.114Z</wsu:Expires>
                </trust:Lifetime>
                <wsp:AppliesTo xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy">
                    <wsa:EndpointReference xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
                        <wsa:Address>http://idibilling.com/webservices</wsa:Address>
                    </wsa:EndpointReference>
                </wsp:AppliesTo>
                <trust:RequestedSecurityToken>
                    <xenc:EncryptedData Type="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#Element" xmlns:xenc="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
                        <xenc:EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#aes256-cbc"/>
                        <KeyInfo xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
                            <e:EncryptedKey xmlns:e="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
                                <e:EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#rsa-oaep-mgf1p">
                                    <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
                                </e:EncryptionMethod>
                                <KeyInfo>
                                    <o:SecurityTokenReference xmlns:o="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
                                        <X509Data>
                                            <X509IssuerSerial>
                                                <X509IssuerName>XXXXXXXXX</X509IssuerName>
                                                <X509SerialNumber>123456789</X509SerialNumber>
                                            </X509IssuerSerial>
                                        </X509Data>
                                    </o:SecurityTokenReference>
                                </KeyInfo>
                                <e:CipherData>
                                    <e:CipherValue>Y1fId9FFPZfhSOhiPj61Mbqx3fdIpvUeY0SlwTXdOSDkS06PFks7pM209sfwakkvxkdAG7iovy7gpDFlmAkq7ePKMCZhztgBJWnHuzylB3sEyncXXQCrzbJDIqYUXqp/ZJ7SVBp/XPq/jtimhCiHrbm5SGIW+v3R+Zf1lWWUsn9QXaqbj00uKhWKl1EV491SoswCYXAtUdSRSd+Ex+ATK9gvO95LShdUvbEwWYYKyoxKuKyE6sjBiMUan3N/qBK0z7ku0fopRKjbfWPRbdB7tEM7n2f08fxScDzPjFTGsCZz4kDEm7UaRLOYeCQVkhH4tFrS+D/V/AgVU9HErTmuow==</e:CipherValue>
                                </e:CipherData>
                            </e:EncryptedKey>
                        </KeyInfo>
                        <xenc:CipherData>
                            <xenc:CipherValue>di2ADzpQFrKWQh4S6m5PsadBvghJfb5fJgZwW7FA2Q4bVgTcm2YhDLOxei6mVWuaOzykh4ft0OQdiViN5Hn/mJYVIzk/p6zUV9/oqaiSpQT9VgZTa1ngtOnszP8H+A1+BdQ+jC4I6VrKHMiA8hXsvED5dhXxHj3k2dBWxwc22+TjswDQHWNzn2bUqJShWSy0JYPsjlTrG6AhVyPLlrPCQXRGMnrLraL3aaAlBHXlTw02TyE2J89BHV6PNrC0TsymQRGH69kOE1GqslQsLOqD0IMS3XEjGY2ZPlqoczSgJXZr9dirbX6jJ1svRRhLT1XhaGpXwJ5l5r/0IAAVSJUAoDBhZBizy5rNfaDZH4UA2IRRVw1J+1RHY1PypjBu0H43NQdODHVt0WtaTaXQhaZs216wX9BbWaK9mySMr9ZTgB3t9LX2PmwfOYiPRrdeyTO2+BxLJOxJ+y1DYQ35RIotQJK9VfekINNeMSS99ARCpc28ueDcdreNcCAjay95ONtEASs9784dwgs3YQ0in84VAxKOT+s321I3h15qPW90uS+5enB+qW5n9E+yTajEW2GO20GDiH8amoFEH+3drpCksDOJjCb5TVcNkqhX6DjekiaCBv+j1Cb6Ixj4YnAF2Rw3ca1UsgZ/xs651j56F1NcxoEZe6VmC729T6t3hVF/2p2nsKqgLt8wsDqhqLae0ZCfK7U41FTuFPPUOk1NNaH5IQzLt3eEsHGzaCi5nh0MUJ5iadiqnM5BxaxD7GRA0fI7DH3YTeq2+hNRHGtPLbSwxddKiiBEJE1PVyv7W8CiJWm5RxjNvc+sf6VSvROTST/mU8/C5u/bVCSUK5Pi/JC24bezW2jk9TiJr0LPU0MdYn6mb7Gr3Z/91owRTL16+P+j9Xpm5lv2oUr1ThXmAry177keXygx/8lezM/5AhJf8DUYMRmJ+IBfs9fMWPPx5ZM4jPECKJGI8o19h2I6guPBzHWyDM3ZH2Khh8GCqOf1WOZNKgxCTW5XBsimMbmfEVDpGGK7hAH1YaKx8LLnugkcwFf8l8lEO7KurKXKUzZ/bKf9JvUoGD7RxQrYpA/6kRxirAIklrKE9tCClgqEnY9+zmksdd2chNbNFy75XGVuNfEl8dAu5A6v80p9TloEQsFMEyb3E/vN5m1T+jp/E9K246of/P/Oz7iblDpHhNbbfV7iZeiO3NEyAlDrxKJAGbE4tFhciKVMA8MEYNYUxikCBgjtOHrO/WPS4woBpvy8ZMnOP2/PbsKD65tMJ3tYu2y57nWva17+rFRxm5U85lwLt3aMrtPQS6OshuvhPIGvOei1D35R7HnU8W9wrw94xKrGJoYoJ52msFIeCpHKaeYaKDoIhEHO4g2rGqYKoW8BBYglsxs7llD8lysZHIcaI9mxZcPTtpz2m6gIoB0MbLaQ92+VDFj8M99cx+O5SM44F/clsKm0+W4y6WokcoFfFMSmasODQRe6D/U3tn6jpTtcXpZnPUDgy//STVl8JYU+g7VG2BYEiAgPiBZ0dKkE5+Og8Zj6wG5qTgrmrN360qnjr4EdxlhsidgxpgWURFS+TZpl0PTh/WrsakaZ9ZpJ9kz8s/rPNTQXucomlERL95mXMfkZYalsvW5NsIx0vQudPV+6LfnbgmWreowa5qdyib4v86rN9tGepz8C4pgs0osj1tnxW9069MvtM2jg0KbtAyLRIHkTovznBHU6DmVVNn2+iNcz7xdVp8K6LnBbv+a7+/HPTGLhy/76og66kpH67B0tRHGVdiJDlh6UyZN4Z0G3qgHJM5uJ2JGYuH7p5uUDiZKPR/RdIQGiuUUXbvY+8QiyFA2qJv6+9VbctX7xEMmULRW/Geo3JaQqG2Zvl5tkXp2m6z2eKFijeVl5P/4mLmiIFw+gqURx840hK/Hmx2+BU69V0hRMlhpLW/X1zPaFwTzdxSX3A1hXLh6TmS5AOmA6KqJ+egrBs+YKmHKXQj4BI/OaYeWhOaXAqCdozljR21O0pSMU2uVYaXwOVE00LV/hlbyjnt2/9iJUWtoi9uTje8ipq6wgFMBHub3pQll7Wy8mrttVx+QVOeh6/y8FRtfCvDoBax/MiiPW40ATYkqSz8AsAGvlYT49RcVo8Vt4VBpb3VjgzsjD+PHEsonQ+0nkRXXrnh6XMxY87OjY40UhqzH01U/JUToZVG5lknf0kEfoFDYJWzJNJl77oukns85MsN1oXWuhvu+JcJ5/V/+UxGXxv7OFv3shP+5N+KhF9wKK7w1yVu84MRK5RcVDY0guAfnTJsAgHHHiWIj8TUamcmuKWClXT/bziFeQtt5QkRVPGW/gTUMbIs2ccK39H+auFqWTofAqcm6cVFUsn5M9jda7TGXOT2mOQDMpTEkkunbgotRMstPZBXXKjy2sRCQ/4wruCVzqLuiJIaY8sTuL8HSDiwwy6AcKn55ebz1xZr0vgvfgLYM+y7RqblxNcna8SsaG/WmV2QEUUzVsgl/FVGz7+nLi7Dw2F59SXTBIkCYIEkFfKFqsyCehUkjH7cbxAsffCpvlT2GWq3ReD2CfValm86MhfbdiR4b3Vku33224FWc6w6Y7MKY5ugLVwaOApPhMRo28OJ3kfsOoQewBIK3LrM+O24qlXHsTfnonbCq3I8q+ZF/InWFgOmxQ+EoHigEHxFyDyFq4ICi4AZPtZsaiBpwv4e1Oh7hvRJw9Db8/UyeU4/n1ccEDGk79kDgRaZWIXMOBguafkON759Y9fA5JsoQkFGun7JYzx55pJ5gmXuXe9cifNTQGepnG1/9mHQ5FZcWNzyU7iGMNSJ03XGpNZoXLhbupCj+OYQpthliw1x4bVMNXlZ4faUnbZWf1nrEvrCiwv77TDgKKaXJsSoiE51OoDRgz+KXWP4kkR/HsUfL0z5UveRsgS+DoZsPKnRcYuzYYQ1nFanjLsTQPmgujkDYQYnu51xQUfIQx5MkDGbRJqUlrmovJLo8XUn9R9w3ZQbcqDxJGUpLsPjLuQJQubjv1RzuBOqwrOzCEQEOliXGDJMYM9Dnez0PYCE6vLD2A+IwPJXyhFclzrnpx9J4UbAzQYqDuU4kO2hzc2wcHK8Cg6xyGn6dVq902sXRdc0x5pXfJvUYK8yR7qo1JZHBiSW8/Naqu2vV3g/b87C1dgpQZdjid4qXGFaUmBEJlUn/I5Mv57TTXuO5VwC0jN+XWyd3HREkYIwkrT0OGhMP2hcVVqvZ0FrDwUWJtDdJCjaZicANqNTb+0SEsZVkmBSuvIeSsDiAxlLmBZsjFzNOYhyKExk2GYwEF3jgmBdsxCLmjqPpz+FM1rq9E6rABbVMe4ESRTp80mZX9wkzAcCSBT4uAfOfIIqlZeeAXmeNNCeQIEnd/jaskrjlZNuqjLqF5X6NG56T/cNodoTCCfrbn2DnC9Mq2H+gev1SVgbUWikHsjH/iIwqJtkRR0li8auSR/WxQ3zOfFg7lXClwNcvnauyvRnVYzjDJVLi9NyST+CUTqerH5b9iGCF4hmaLxfhRjzoa7cKF2j5WtSnKJCs+ARhPqq/1T6znukGDJ82/NRiVs2bwApIodXrcBst4cBSSQNUvwtUMX7ogt5+xouWuSBmSvH9Ll2BRk47ibf3fjXxK+/z7KfIFlck6nHFSHnL6BJR25KOD6Tgw0YR5S1Z8n3DHdrjDnGCd11KI6GIMRz3VKes5h82TyG6NoFFzHpLdubO5m+kmmnDAbnaQQe3p78oZa4i9U6buXxC1AIgEEgzEt9/r9HuCbu4KW/pNm0N3zEk7+0vzJmgnKsEh2644S5kZvEHpXZ7twDJEftReb5/LkJCwiJyq7LVL/4o0LVVRZsEd0QmBxkyIb2rrT/sYC8i9fXx7f0TSAZN2MEHGnl5JVQrYe8N8l2haXWzxiu2btjtdrNJz3jsM3GgZ4sUkhgJp72ZnMd9FTD2QMOkJiA/mLOWprG6N/uH0kueCyYB7zxlKf9758RVlaFb4tgHS6YhN73Cn9kkaDe7rWDeKbyUg3R0vOSTnCIygMhUkz3TqgkDKmWbMoZnfs07B4bLwpvLrddWCO4JBZh0teBQKBu1phMdBnNeMvr7tlF81LzKD01rZeQ5lxFgm2gjlC7+0E+0LoPiHetjFLaOtMW4N3xjr5+CeCxftgvot81hn4evBnueovePikuSo1LYn6rmVOfpsC9CLJ3s8ozE47Kao1Ym+t81hp7b97nPFxVCndcB/CmXebovnmfG9abyFtISep7D5KReB1qM03ZnL+WBKfsjuKMQPbPKdVWhy3F6UpNKG/ZYaBDjP6mQwog8UrQNBZYcqFDA2pE3lLpor/uLPKzrSjxBnxZhE9qKv3KYxbFC3CpA2dZ79HuzGQRIiPA6UXpIksOr+J4vO8v69NCrKefN5nMu4WTYb7DR6GHg56ckSiBGQhAKUO/ZmsgutjRHdHI5V9eTlTC8SGwxVd44Qv/XrsTPafT3Tz80tuPT4e3SAX6T5eGW5fksRkccgLLx7ieEZP05cclEMEkl1FdNILNY/6nJeYe27jmpvAR2wB5CWvcI8w/G7BYU2Nma0rSvaMVN/c5PN6Vw8B4eIgaG223vKzUAqjSQEb3k4VIPdyG8yksZWvWD8QMEiWMXvWjjeB4N52Ahc32N+C2mKJ5ovC1dfRa3n9Hdv7iuLFdiTY13jemvJO6De5jZIdklyuiD37ACCoR8H9Ehp364pgl4aY/j1EpCg8ZPvd5P8c5esEnXoA3+woQRM0q6sSNimBJqvH0Jf4C0kZ6q2nUHkiP7k0A04cmxCaCJaEcrjdtCUkBPk+Tlmz2S3PIT0s6jEjwpZjTgj4la+sqlIYT47cwLtPQWkT3XfrnalwfMrDA9RP0vJ6zPu8ehC2D2pJWNoRumNrDKH3HtzBy+l7UljXzXS3+ZQMdEFS1OJsYE07qi8gc/BgYJO8R9GHkosJtbFT4SJ5+sXA6F37yOTBr/QR/NkoqWOEI5AGhpe+LIUw12nrVoE/03/k5kFncY53vpemKlPMN3WSeKWC2sTZRUAknJegBB48rHm9WALgqmX8ZqB9RqfDt/uJVbnz5QYv5NjtgthOyfewny/UPvxMNSpP356j0Mcqa7mroQLaujYfDNBn4U8VJCmlhZh6E5+tLlmlZekDUzpjLaLT4KeS/wSxVpP0paEzZrphb9zxH00fl9Z1g+lu9GlzKUMCoWMpX6vA6dODT1YLyC4tVIiGwLXAsv62oYg7GaFrmiFfhk0++Vmb5mtsnPhBY8ii0MDWadioMtLZqh3aPiXJwNkPYdXFb5GwZXxpqCEZYCvRiJ6dixQ/PpH5+Y7Ub8xfOCCKU8lQWxnjsiV1MaL5evGIMSzsh26MCaswSbKijryxaFU1FegKMOuustdzu9jk0fIuCp/wih5DqgeTdWu90VEL/ooLWwUGbvSs4JzUiQ9IOslXH87Ajyr6PGezooPqGDdw6iE0kl6iBKgcRQsyxIZTNq8To3+ikbw0YztrFoPLtmHBzIbP7+Ixq5lacWKhJ2Hwo+B7Qlg9OoTgRGZWBFLRUg2A7CZ3nLyo2sRkc4+uRr3Rux4MQ6zAFYz1Tds5CuqKwOuLI+uR62UzJYbhKGrZxal30VYdbY0GhS7FBArjpB3m/4grbHfzGgzzoNRwP63HOlgmEC87lN/K2qS5aIMhDC3opfaYbhQOyOgpsmhjQzZXeeBtIj0lgiPl3dmiXCEPHNWtkjxHjtRcp/EXAfR6uPeP/UWv4mI5kpZMbR6V4nHQDLKVdsfRQXUj2iqOwYwNti1KYa3vwMYBuuULndjfLJ51QXdjbnIe12shVSnZNivQZa3oEb7Df+g0vpByAiNVNMS+ZCBa6+JwhOnjtYdfd6kOjM40WaFu/ea/DQ3QnEcRTwc9W9ViTTn0nLsgXEIWHKo2R/Ckj2ncrKlnOCrogq+Jy4BqB+PBtIyyuyMm53loztfXjJnDeyb6w0kekV4DlDUrTaDNgTzqeJzF85KtDIEzoCXrQdje/JfZYwbYMzKG5qtk831QFIZSLmH+FyBmsRJgmLYXiCd+4GHZ1HQsbuATt8uaR1myL9NfrrpQJ3MQEaoWrx+sy1oA4zIKDO7z7aV2UEf5Ov2Xmp8HYVqss3zUGiOX9g6Wy2GHzci9A7lwFLw8q1D9vqmejf+93GI/GAyNAMmpz6XO6AIxNOQXp8bG9+iaHF91DfQQmRCcuvxinaBOZD4TMNe+F2KSfldUwh4vHhthgTUmtKTY/jiqDUbsPGSGPTTMJFu7vFvKAA1vlk9VOsehwIpE90ja1J/xbsT49NxlOG96JdiBrsOqUXU55Ad647x286g1jornxjaSNLxetjkE19FjLM6AMlEB2eKn6dtDzv6x05hlTlJ7/9nruvvkLY3V6MFQSMokoid8pXqmjAJc2tdXRD57lQJpCTFN+K8ZA4I+oc98HAHEPl/DggIjAX3mjjp7DWDyWqd9s3cnagSdxd9RxCXzJdIjlA9YXPN96qQ/lpL1NBzXBrPVgRUixEYuEPLlhzqdcnCT9WYptA4c2pOBvq6V7TGg8gksmhyApgRCeozPASmwZsVXYNZdAjdTNfvN4GZolUYKmfc0vHZpG6MUWeriF4liXhOqDCG2ZIlnb66tVxMSr9HwX/iFlhbrqTtrzYYHnzM28aUjg9rLNTCjNOAoMNkMms2N7anuzoyuJ2seiS97shvc/UydAJZXG9twJ9f7Bw2s0y51VboVX/WLAtJ79Vh+ZDOFWK7SWAywtmO+u85TaEOOXkDR7nRZCZCtjMxEwfAgV8Ezzfn5D1aZuptAc1H+37r+TOEhtRZtuALC9Rk/z1vlocGCfBs0tjrPXfKMS2kMYk/6C9BjkwOqSErXjrNxyAkb8ISBOJlPQrF1AYtCs928oAUH2xH2Id4l4R9WAfs5Ry2mQj2xGEiw68D3wg/Y3UAaYD6XQukYiUlrJ42lDyk69s2eSMZ8+QAYMRJgj3QtjhHq7Y2XhNN1Q4KhvVQ0WMSZ+B3mktQuJ3SXIi1IfZnkfV266hN8WDkFf8P5knSiyIJ0Hb4GbIbdaSgIOMw7RIiJ2bEXwg8Kxt2Iq6v+4wu0ZmwJ8igRg1w4BWDG6fCZhMSoS3B0UijrST+JzNTFsKU/SVrErUP4agIpYt5ytfiJtgwHD2R85AD5yaIeWn2/hrqNqMW8/ahoJDN7jGCGKTY4B11hWC8QkTI6Q5+WRIU2vQRongrwOFAaf9F29BDxFYCT+p2BEGLkOwRVghpKTaI9Y+4dlRR6mquTwIJ4jsdEeP94q6VgrJNqRPxjlJUVDWF/wpxT5p3teS+xO3c++NANS3mFXiSdRtl9etrbF1XNQ8sJ0PYYFRYn+UJqoJ/78HfWQkdtsReqJlGSu1AD13VJ9gvCNSxcxEPq6skMr1KZnBPsdLEAmPeXSWf5J6pRR59oXDtOWeQlYz3d55+btBzO7AVuYmArW96vLcuEXOlFTZLlJ0LKHzDT5Wi0Cq9ihlctnLmmRmwJ1y/Wenx/eeLYvIFblBohmrVKZao0HbVAjIR2H08fQpczAgThdG8qVxjaNzgZRzWVbIaXn1efEsLQ0gDcNftb2f+sH491h6MHDI4kcLQZ0jc0V7rJE4XUya1RsU+FGMW7Fareq3E024pALJbnu0C3TgPu1Acvv4ajN4HUC7qwGGeXPy1XGUN+OqM</xenc:CipherValue>
                        </xenc:CipherData>
                    </xenc:EncryptedData>
                </trust:RequestedSecurityToken>
                <trust:RequestedProofToken>
                    <trust:BinarySecret>bOkZdTCufrwieMmOdcO5T1e+JSzlDB5SlcLhPgWwlsE=</trust:BinarySecret>
                </trust:RequestedProofToken>
                <trust:RequestedAttachedReference>
                    <o:SecurityTokenReference k:TokenType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/oasis-wss-saml-token-profile-1.1#SAMLV1.1" xmlns:o="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:k="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/oasis-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.1.xsd">
                        <o:KeyIdentifier ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/oasis-wss-saml-token-profile-1.0#SAMLAssertionID">_a13abe92-0956-407b-ae40-8266bd218521</o:KeyIdentifier>
                    </o:SecurityTokenReference>
                </trust:RequestedAttachedReference>
                <trust:RequestedUnattachedReference>
                    <o:SecurityTokenReference k:TokenType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/oasis-wss-saml-token-profile-1.1#SAMLV1.1" xmlns:o="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:k="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/oasis-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.1.xsd">
                        <o:KeyIdentifier ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/oasis-wss-saml-token-profile-1.0#SAMLAssertionID">_a13abe92-0956-407b-ae40-8266bd218521</o:KeyIdentifier>
                    </o:SecurityTokenReference>
                </trust:RequestedUnattachedReference>
                <trust:TokenType>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.0:assertion</trust:TokenType>
                <trust:RequestType>http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-trust/200512/Issue</trust:RequestType>
                <trust:KeyType>http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-trust/200512/SymmetricKey</trust:KeyType>
            </trust:RequestSecurityTokenResponse>
        </trust:RequestSecurityTokenResponseCollection>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

What we want to accomplish is to consume this SAML Response so we can use it in a security header like this one:

```xml
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
<s:Header>
    <o:Security xmlns:o="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
        <u:Timestamp u:Id="_0" xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
            <u:Created>2019-05-21T05:05:05.573Z</u:Created>
            <u:Expires>2019-05-21T05:10:05.573Z</u:Expires>
        </u:Timestamp>

        <xenc:EncryptedData Type="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#Element" xmlns:xenc="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
            <xenc:EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#aes256-cbc"/>
            <KeyInfo xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
                <e:EncryptedKey xmlns:e="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
                    <e:EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#rsa-oaep-mgf1p">
                    <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
                    </e:EncryptionMethod>
                    <KeyInfo>
                    <o:SecurityTokenReference xmlns:o="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
                    <X509Data>
                    <X509IssuerSerial>
                    <X509IssuerName>XXXXXXX</X509IssuerName>
                    <X509SerialNumber>123456789</X509SerialNumber>
                    </X509IssuerSerial>
                    </X509Data>
                    </o:SecurityTokenReference>
                    </KeyInfo>
                    <e:CipherData>
                        <e:CipherValue>LGRkzAOljXa1jSLVJijxJoYtsEf0ac5zZKxBHxEddowiMSDUI03Ggw5GTvl5/pf/yh6V5sbO17HQtbudN7PBmbGb8fXj07bhJzjqgnibyWTF+Nn0zk/Hq+hwqNZY+MT27LoRgEshKuGLl7ll/lQTvB7fjLMXxwZsyQ2T1NcgKgoyj0BqOifPQfD1ruoiNRaTlvWC+cxpz0k4UcwN6LjQx2QfOsEDYevoIhxAPZwy1eyGhExwPaGTgbrzVvqLLszzkBjCKT+rSZ7mof1cGjRAl9tGXoyiBW/KEhlqy5N15LU141zHQpAwwBhOVNbsYPWQGc1JCgZgNu5T0914yfmGmw==</e:CipherValue>
                    </e:CipherData>
                </e:EncryptedKey>
            </KeyInfo>
            <xenc:CipherData>
                <xenc:CipherValue>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</xenc:CipherValue>
            </xenc:CipherData>
        </xenc:EncryptedData>
        <Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
            <SignedInfo>
                <CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
                <SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#hmac-sha1"/>
                <Reference URI="#_0">
                    <Transforms>
                        <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
                    </Transforms>

                    <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
                    <DigestValue>dl7TJsR0gVfPKQ/CVl2eDQpa0Ic=</DigestValue>
                </Reference>
            </SignedInfo>
            <SignatureValue>T+DZmdJXWeNnnfMXA0bZOKNJ5b8=</SignatureValue>
            <KeyInfo>
                <o:SecurityTokenReference k:TokenType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/oasis-wss-saml-token-profile-1.1#SAMLV1.1" xmlns:o="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:k="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/oasis-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.1.xsd">
                    <o:KeyIdentifier ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/oasis-wss-saml-token-profile-1.0#SAMLAssertionID">_b49d8768-4b11-4032-95f0-d4c85bc3dad0</o:KeyIdentifier>
                </o:SecurityTokenReference>
            </KeyInfo>
        </Signature>
    </o:Security>
</s:Header>

<s:Body><CustomerLookup xmlns="http://webservices.idibilling.com/Customer/1.0"><Requestor xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><AuthorizationToken>deprecated</AuthorizationToken><RegisterID>0</RegisterID></Requestor><Request xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><CustomerID><AuthenticatedKey>deprecated</AuthenticatedKey><ID>25020</ID></CustomerID><ResponseGroups><ResponseGroup>BalanceSummary</ResponseGroup></ResponseGroups></Request></CustomerLookup></s:Body></s:Envelope>
```

So far we do not have any knowledge on how to get the following value to construct the Security Header:

1. Digest Value
2. Signature Value
3. Security Token Reference

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: *"..how to get the following value..."* What part are you having difficulty with? Extracting values from the response OR constructing the headers, because the latter is a very different question. If it's the latter, please update your question with the code you used to construct those headers.